# vb.net FTP - works in some cases

Tags: vb.net

i currently have this code as my FTP code (Which works a charm!)

```
 Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
                test.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
                Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient
                    wc.UploadData("ftp://" & My.Settings.username & ":" & My.Settings.password & "@ftp." & My.Settings.server & My.Settings.imagelocation & filename & ".jpg", ms.ToArray())

                End Using
            End Using
```

however i have a new username and directory etc, and they contain "@" this is my username for example: "snap@example.com"

but my username before would be for instance "test" you see without the "@" im guessing its because it messes with the "@ftp" part, Any suggestions how to fix?

Comment: If I understand correctly: your URL becomes `ftp://snap@example.com:password@ftp.server/imagelocation/filename.jpg`?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

Encode your username and password using System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode before creating your URL.

**Long answer:**

According to [the IETF's RFC 1738](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/rfc1738.txt), which is a standards track document about URLs, it explicitly says

> Within the user and password field, any ":", "@", or "/" must be encoded.

The [actual URL spec document](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt) does not explicitly mention encoding special characters in usernames and passwords, but I think it's implied that you can encode them. And it says

> Because a % sign always indicates
>     an encoded character, a URL may be made safer simply by encoding
>     any characters considered unsafe, while leaving already encoded.

So you should percent-escape any special charaters in your URL, and in the case of an '@' that's %40.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the following classes provided by .net:

- FtpWebRequest
- WebRequestMethods
- NetworkCredential

  ```
          Private Shared Sub UploadFileToFTP(source As String)
          Try
                  Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(source)
                  Dim ftpfullpath As String = ftpurl
                  Dim ftp As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath), FtpWebRequest)
                  ftp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword)

                 ftp.KeepAlive = True
                 ftp.UseBinary = True
                 ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

                 Dim fs As FileStream = File.OpenRead(source)
                 Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}
                 fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                 fs.Close()

                 Dim ftpstream As Stream = ftp.GetRequestStream()
                 ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                 ftpstream.Close()
          Catch ex As Exception
                   Throw ex
          End Try
          End Sub
  ```